# boost::asio::async_read_until not calling handler

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm learning how to use Boost:asio library with Serial Port. I wrote some code using synchrous write and read and I now want to use asynchrous but it's not working.
Simple Example:

```
void readHandler(const boost::system::error_code&,std::size_t);

streambuf buf;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    io_service io;
    serial_port port(io,PORT);

        if(port.isopen()){
           while(1){
            // ... getting std::string::toSend from user ...

                write(port,buffer(toSend.c_str(),toSend.size())); 

                async_read_until(port,buf,'\n',readHandler); // <= it's returning but not calling readHandler at all
           }
           port.close(); 
        }

}

void readHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error,std::size_t bytes_transferred){

    std::cout << "readHandler()" << std::endl;
    //... reading from buf object and calling buf.consume(buf.size()) ...
}
```

**async_read_until()** it's returning but not calling ***readHandler()***. If I change to synchrous read, it's reading from port OK. I also checking ***buf*** object each while loop and it's empty. What I'm doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Janm has pointed out you need to call io.run for the async_read_until to work.

But...

You also need to convert the write over to an async_write, as the sync and async calls don't really work well together within asio. What you would need to do is the following:

setup first async_write
call io.run

in your write handler setup the async_read_until

in your read handler setup the next async_write

Comment: Thanks. But I'm confused now... so what is different between calling synch read (blocking function) or calling async read and io.run() (also blocking) ?

Comment: I found that async is really only usefull if you have other things that need to be done while reading/writing. You would have these done by using the io_service's post method and those will happen along with the async i/o calls. If your program can be constructed as event driven, the async works very well, otherwise, you might be better staying with the sync calls, but don't mix the two.

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading boost documentation all the time and still not understand everything but ... step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the run() method on the io_service for the callbacks to work. In your loop, you need `io.run()`.

Comment: But io.run() is blocking right ??? So must I create another thread to not block my loop ??

Comment: Calling a blocking function is only a problem if you have something else to do. If you want to have everything be asynchronous you don't need more than one thread unless you have CPU bound tasks.

Comment: I've added io.run() after async_read_until() but readHandler is called only once (next loops only writes but without response).