# boost::asio::async_read does not callback my handler function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asyncsocket

I am working with `boost::asio` for `TCP` communication between a client & server app both of which are written by me. I'd initially written this with synchronous data reading that is using `boost::asio::read`. The `sync_read` is working all fine except that I am unable to so do a `socket.cancel` during a read operation. This has become quite a constraint & hence **I am now trying convert my synchronous read to do `async_read` mechanism**.

**Following was my synchronous read mechanism which really well. I do 2 reads. Firstly get the packet header then get the packet data which works pretty well ->**

```
size_t Read_Data_Sync(std::vector<unsigned char> & msg_body) {
  //fetch the header
  MyMessageHeader msg_header;
  boost::system::error_code err_code;
  size_t bytes_received = boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(&msg_header, sizeof(msg_header)), err_code);

  if (bytes_received <= 0 || err_code)
    return 0;

  err_code.clear();
  msg_body.resize(msg_header.size);

  //fetch the body
  bytes_received = boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(msg_body), err_code);
  if (bytes_received <= 0 || error_code)
    return 0;

  return bytes_received;
}
```

Above function used to get called continuously from a `thread` on the client side which I call it a reader thread **`like so` ->**

```
auto data_reader_thread = std::thread {[this] {
    while(run_thread) {
        Read_Data_Sync();
    }
}};
```

**Following is how I am changing this to make the read mechanism `async` ->**

The reader thread stays that same except that it now calls another read function which I have coded to do read data in an `async` way

```
auto data_reader_thread = std::thread {[this] {
    while(run_thread) {
        Read_Data_Async();
    }
}};
```

*I have made the `msg_body` & `msg_header` as member variables in my class. The renewed logic is that `Read_Data_Async` is called from thread function continuously. `Read_Data_Async` calls `boost::asio::async_read` binding 
the address of `Handle_Read_Header` as callback which in turn again does a `boost::asio::async_read` to read the message body passing a handler callback to receive `message_body`*

```
void Read_Data_Async() 
{
    //firstly read message header
    MyMessageHeader msg_header;
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(&msg_header, sizeof(msg_header)), boost::bind(&TCPSession::Handle_Read_Header, this,
                                                                                                             boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void Handle_Read_Header(const boost::system::error_code & error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    //now read the message body
    if (!error && bytes_transferred > 0) {
        boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(msg_body), boost::bind(&TCPSession::Handle_Read_Body, this,
                                                                                                                 boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error: " << error << "\n";
    }
}


void Handle_Read_Body(const boost::system::error_code & error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error && bytes_transferred > 0) {
        // msg_body has the data read from socket
    }
    else if (error != boost::asio::error::eof) {
        cout << "Error: " << error << "\n";
    }
}
```

**The problem I am facing now is that the callback `Handle_Read_Header` never gets called back !!** What is wrong with what I doing ? I looked through quite a few related posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670014/boostasioasync-read-until-not-calling-handler) trying to resolve my 
problem but again that link is suggesting to call `io.run` because its about `boost::asio::async_read_until` not `boost::asio::async_read`.

**Is my above logic correct wrt to `boost::asio::async_read` ? What should I get `asio` to call back my handler function ?**

Comment: Which thread calls the `run()` on the `io_service` object?

Comment: my main thread calls `io_service::run()` & `io_service` is on main thread. How can I make this work with a separate reader thread ?

Answer (score 1):

You must run `io_service::run()` somewhere ¹

Actually, the whole idea of doing asynchronous IO is that you do *NOT* need the separate threads for reading/writing: full duplex is entirely possible on a single thread.

---

¹ or some more complicated loop with run_one, poll or poll_one

Comment: `io_service::run()` is called on the main thread which does the connect with server as well. I am bound to call the reads on a worker thread because mine is a application which continuously updates data at fast rate. hence I am bound to have a thread which call read in a loop. may be I should do the connect as well in my reader thread if not connected ?

Comment: The service `run` completes as soon as no completion handlers are there. Make sure you post the next operation before the last one completes. Or use `io_service::work`. The sample show how all of this works

Comment: isn't this quite a constraint ? how does it matter for asio whether I call `io_service::run()` on main thread or some other thread ? How can I make this work with read being continuously called on a worker thread ? someone should have faced the same problem.

Comment: @SegmentationFault I said nothing about where to run the service. The opposite really. And yes many people faced the same choices. Start with the samples

Comment: sorry if I misunderstood. I am doing `io_service.run` on main thread & all my reads on a worker thread. this kind of design will not work with `async_read` ?

Comment: You can do all reads and writes on the main thread as well. This is the point of asynchrony